# Get last three letters in dict python

Tags: python

An example like:

```
 text = ' "west best worst first tapping snapping in a pest the straining 
 singing forest living'
 a_dict = get_last_three_letters_dict(text) 
 remove_less_than_2(a_dict)
 print("1.")
 print_dict_in_key_order(a_dict)    

 text = 'Kublai Khan does not necessarily believe everything Marco Polo says 
 when he describes the cities visited on his expeditions but the emperor of 
 the Tartars does continue listening to the young Venetian with greater 
 attention and curiosity than he shows any other messenger or explorer of his'
 a_dict = get_last_three_letters_dict(text) 
 remove_less_than_2(a_dict)
 print("2.")
 print_dict_in_key_order(a_dict)
```

I'm trying to convert the string to lower case and then returns a dictionary object which has keys which are the last three letters of any words in the string of text with length greater than 2, and corresponding values which are the number of words in the parameter string of text which end with these last three letters.

The testing code removes any pairs in the resulting dictionary where the last three letters occur just the once in the string of text, I tried the function below, it doesn't work.

```
def get_last_three_letters_dict(sentence):
      sentence = dict(sentence)
      tails = []
      for letter in sentence:
            if len(name) > 2:
               tails.append(name[-3:].lower())
      return (''.join(tails) + ":")
```

expected:

```
 1.
 est : 4
 ing : 5
 rst : 2

 2.
 han : 2
 his : 2
 ing : 2
 oes : 2
 the : 4
```

Comment: What will you expect `dict(sentence)` to do? It makes no sense calling dict on a sentence..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that collects the last three letters of all the words in the sentence that are longer than 2 letters, and then returns a dict of those that occur more than once.

```
from collections import Counter

def get_letter_dict(sentence):
    sentence = sentence.lower().split()
    c = Counter(word[-3:] for word in sentence if len(word) > 2)
    return dict((a,b) for a,b in c.items() if b > 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the function below returns a dictionary, the order of key-value pairs it will return return is random. But it does what you wanted.

(Noticed that when I edited it to remove key-value pairs with value 1, I made a mistake. Fixed it. Now it should work the way you wanted it to work)

```
def get_last_three_letters_dict(sentence):
    #Split the sentence into a list of words
    words = sentence.split()

    #Create an empty list to store tails in
    tails = []

    #Create list of last three letters of all words with length greater than 2
    for word in words:
        if len(word) > 2:
            tails.append(word[-3:].lower())

    #create empty dictionary for word tails + tail frequencies
    tail_dict = dict()

    for tail in tails:
    #Add a key if tail is not already in dictionary. Set its value to 1.
        if tail not in tail_dict.keys():
            tail_dict[tail] = 1

    #If the tail is already a key, add 1 to its value
        else:
            tail_dict[tail] = tail_dict[tail] + 1

    #Delete key-value pairs with value 1
    for key in list(tail_dict.keys()):  
        if tail_dict[key] == 1:            
            del tail_dict[key]
    return tail_dict
```